# Why are jquery mobile css themes not applying to urls with parameters or /?

Tags: php, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a simple mobile site that has two pages.  I used the theme roller to create the look I want and when I access the url without a prameter, the theme applies itself.  However, if I add a parameter or just a / to the end of the url, I get the default theme.  Here is an example url: http://www.devtownbeam.com/mobile/mobileevents.php
and if you add just a /  to the end, it changes 
http://www.devtownbeam.com/mobile/mobileevents.php/

Here is the html and document ready function

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/townbeammobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageone" >
  <div data-role="header">
   <img style="display:block;" src="http://townbeam.com/siteimages/tbtransparentCrop.png" alt="TownBeam.com" /> 
  <h1 style="color:#9aac3c;">Atlantic Highlands</h1>    

<div id="mobNav" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="margin-bottom:0px;border-bottom:0px;" >
    <a  data-role="button" href="mobileplaces.php" style="width:49%;border-bottom:0px;" >Go<br>Visit Local Businesses</a>
    <a data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" href="#"  style="width:49%;border-bottom:0px;" >Do<br>Attend Events</a>
</div>

 </div>

<div  data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="b">
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="mobgetevents.php/?_escaped_fragment_=events&calid=townbeam@gmail.com">Town Calendar</option>
        <option value="mobgetevents.php/?_escaped_fragment_=events&calid=cddh69iavn9gqmmcai9s4qdue0@group.calendar.google.com">Giving </option>
        <option value="mobgetevents.php?_escaped_fragment_=events&calid=h1j9lsj20kec8nugnecu4b25h0@group.calendar.google.com">Kids</option>
        <option value="mobgetevents.php/?_escaped_fragment_=events&calid=4btasp0rcfq0skr4c6tuu7g7m8@group.calendar.google.com">Historical</option>
    </select>
</div> 

<div id="theContent" data-role="content" data-theme="b" >
<?php
    include_once ("mobgetevents.php");
?>
</div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
 <h4 style="color:#9aac3c">Your town brought to view</h4>
 </div><!-- /footer -->

</div> 
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#select-choice-1').bind('change', function() {

        $('#theContent').load($("#select-choice-1 option:selected").attr('value'), function(){
            $("#pageone").trigger("pagecreate");
        });
    }); 


});
</script>
```

Comment: Because style sheets are not loaded, and if you locally host jquery and JQM, your website won't be initialised as JQM. When add `/` at the end, browser identifies mobile.php as a directory and looks for links in _head_ inside that directory. Browser will end up finding nothing. It's like www.foo.com/ broswers look for index.html as a default starting page.

Comment: Thanks Omar, I removed the / from my urls and that worked.

Comment: You're welcome. If yiu have more questions, post them. Good luck.